# A relation between homomorphisms from the polynomial ring zero on an ideal and homomorphisms from the quotient of the polynomial ring by this ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $n\geq 1$, $K$ be a field and $R\neq \{0\}$ a $K$-algebra.

For Ideals $I$ and $J$ of $K[X_1\ldots,X_n]$ with $J\subseteq I$ consider
$$
A(I)=Hom_{Kalg}(K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I,R)
$$
and
$$
B(J)=\{f\in Hom_{Kalg}(K[X_1,\ldots,X_n],R)\mid \forall j\in J:f(j)=0\}.
$$

It is clear that the obvious map $A(I)\subseteq B(J)$ is an injection.

> 1. Given $I$, is there a $J$ (with $J\subseteq I$) such that $A(I)\cong B(J)$ (with the obvious map)?
> 2. Given $J$, is there an $I$ (with $J\subseteq I$) such that $A(I)\cong B(J)$ (with the obvious map)?

E.g., as a partial answer to (2.), I can show that if $J$ is a maximal ideal, then $A(I)= B(J)$ with $I:=J$ since
$$
f(J)=0\Leftrightarrow J\subseteq f^{-1}(0)\Leftrightarrow J=f^{-1}(0)
$$
and every $f:K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\to R$ factorizes through $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/{f^{-1}(0)}$.

Comment: I haven't had my coffee yet this morning, so I need to ask. What is the obvious map? ($A(I)\subseteq B(J)$ is not literally true.)

Comment: You take $f\in Hom_{Kalg}(K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I,R)$, this comes from a $\tilde f\in Hom_{Kalg}(K[X_1,\ldots,X_n],R)$ (determined by where the $X_i$ go) and this is an element of $B(J)$.

Comment: Great, thank you :) So the "$\subseteq$" refers to this injection... got it.

Comment: What are the barriers against $I=J$ making $A(I)\cong B(I)$ all the time? Given $g\in B(I)$, since $I\subseteq \ker(g)$ $g$ factors uniquely through the projection $\pi$ onto quotient by $I$, giving $g'\pi(t)=g(t)$ for all $t\in K[\dots]$. This seems(?) to be an inverse to the proposed inclusion map, but I have a feeling I am thinking about modules morphisms more than ring morphisms, and might have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal property of quotients tells us $B(J) \cong A(J)$. Therefore, the answer is trivially yes, take $I=J$.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is somehow trivial :).